# handing releases using maven effectively like beta/alpha release

Tags: maven

I am using maven for compiling java sources. The version value in pox.xml is 1.0. Now we are planning to release beta.So we have created branch and now onwards we will be running both tot and branch maven project. But the problem is since the  is hardcoded to 1.0 ,it is not possible to distinguish between maven artifacts (pom.xml) for tot and beta in maven repository.

How to recover it ?

Comment: Creating a branch via maven release plugin which will create the branch and can change the versions in pom file for the branch.

Comment: actually we have perforce scm ..after checkout we use the maven which is also get checkout when we checkout perforce scm. now what we did is created a branch using perforce and moved our tot code to it .  since version is hardcoded , branched code also have same hardcoded version=1.0 . and we are using jenkins to build it .